# Why are MutableLiveData variables declared with equals sign (=)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, observers, mutablelivedata

In Kotlin, when declaring the type of variable, a colon is used. Even when declaring LiveData, a colon is used. So why is an *equals sign* used for MutableLiveData? I haven't been able to figure this out. I spent about 2 hours a few days ago trying to understand why my MutableLiveData variable wasn't working only to realize I needed an equals instead of a colon.

**Example:**

```
private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()  
val liveData: LiveData<Int>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin auto detects the type, so you do not need to specify it. These are equivalent

```
val foo: Int = 123
val foo = 123
```

However, if you have a variable that is initialized later, you must provide the type, as otherwise the compiler can't determine what type it is. For instance,

```
class MyClass {
    val foo: Int  // must specify type

    init {
        foo = /* compute foo */
    }
}
```

It has nothing to do with `LiveData` or `MutableLiveData`.

Answer (score 4):

```
val liveData: LiveData<Int>
```

is not meaningful by itself. It also needs to be initialized. I suspect you are looking at a rather common idiom in Android programming, but missed that the next line is still part of definition of `liveData`:

```
val liveData: LiveData<Int>
  get() = _liveData
```

Here the reason you need `: LiveData<Int>` is only because otherwise Kotlin would infer the same type `MutableLiveData<Int>` for `liveData` as for `_liveData`, and the entire point of this idiom is to stop other classes from calling `postValue`/`setValue` on it.

Answer (score 2):

> So why is an equals sign used for MutableLiveData?

Because you are creating an instance of `MutableLiveData`, via its constructor. You are not providing a type — the Kotlin compiler is inferring it from the type of the object you are assigning to the property.

Basically, your statement is shorthand for:

```
private val _liveData: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData<Int>()
```

You can learn more about type inference in [Google's Kotlin docs](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/learn#inference).

Comment: So this means that the compiler infers a type of LiveData? I understand that if I write a class, I can declare a variable of that class using the equals sign. Is LiveData a type and MutableLiveData a class?

Comment: @JamesFutures: "So this means that the compiler infers a type of LiveData?" -- no, it infers a type of `MutableLiveData`. You are creating an instance of `MutableLiveData`. "Is LiveData a type and MutableLiveData a class? " -- [`LiveData` is a class](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData). `MutableLiveData` is [a subclass of `LiveData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData).

Comment: `: MutableLiveData<Int>`, rather.